# Installing Python Modules globally using pip

Tags: python, python-3, terminal, pip, lxterminal

I'm doing a Udemy course using Python, and I recently created a fresh copy of Raspian for my Raspbery Pi 3B+. I have attempted to install the module `pyfiglet`, and used the terminal command `sudo pip install pyfiglet`. However, when I attempt to use it using the IDE Thonny, I get a syntax error saying that the module doesn't exist.

I'm assuming I'd need to install the module to PATH. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tagged with **python-3** but with `sudo pip install pyfiglet` you installed for `python2`, which is out of any support now. Just install it for `python3` with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo pip3 install pyfiglet
```